# which azure id_token validity using some endpoint or classes

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have authenticated successfully against azure AD (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) from of my angular application and got the **id_token**. The **id_token** is passed to another multiple trusted spring boot REST application

From the trusted spring boot REST application which can I validate the **id_token** if it is valid or not. Do we have any endpoint or out of box classes to check the validity of the **id_token** .ie to check if the **id_token** is from the same application and is also valid. The trusted spring boot application have all the below details

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=xxxxx...
azure.activedirectory.client-id=xxxxxx...
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=xxxxx...
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=Users
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Do let me know if need more details on anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check some claims' value of the id_token to check if the id_token is from the same application and is also valid by [decoding id_token](https://jwt.ms/).

For example, you can check the `aud` value to find this id_token is for which app, the `aud` vaule is your app's Application ID; you can use `iat`, `exp`, and`nbf` three claims' value to check the token is valid or not. Here`iat` value is the time that token issued, `nbf` value is the time that token becomes valid, and `exp` value is the time that the token becomes invalid.

For the details, please read [v2.0 tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-id-and-access-tokens#validating-tokens).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.....Can you help me on this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103319/how-to-simple-check-if-the-username-and-password-is-correct-against-azure-ad