# how to simple check if the username and password is correct against Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, authentication

I want to check if the provided username (microsoft azure domain uername) and the password is correct or not. I dont want any tokens on return but rather just to check if the Azure AD user credentials is correct or not.

At present I have went through many blogs and documentation of azure and have seen many oauth2 grant flows. But those I cannot use since it requires certain configuration to be done

Can anyone please help me on this

I am using Java in my server side

Do let me know if need more details on my question

Comment: You can just authenticate and ignore the token returned.

Comment: Actually I want to do that from the server side....when I checked I could find resource owner password grant works only for B2C tenant ...I have a AD existing server which 10000+ of users

Comment: Assume you need the Java equivalent of LoginSilentAsync or AcquireTokenSilentAsync - see a conversation on the topic here http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33922731&ttl=Get+accessToken+from+power+BI+without+GUI+authentication